# Android Matrix postRotation doesn't work

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, orientation

I have an image view in which i would like to show a picture from a URI in the phone

I want to rotate my picture's Bitmap according to the orientation it was taken in - but it doesn't work an always show the picture at the same orientation.

**This is my ImageView:**

```
<!-- picture imageView -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_new_picture_imageview_picture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**This is my matrix function:**

```
/**
 * Get the new picture {@link Bitmap} according to picture's right orientation 
 * @return the picture's {@link Bitmap}
 */
public Bitmap getPictureBitmap()
{
    //if there is a saved instance - return it
    if (pictureBitmap != null)
        return pictureBitmap;
    //decode bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    //rotate bitmap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();               
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);
    //create new rotated bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);     
    return bitmap;      
}
```

**And this is how my Activity is mentioned in the Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.coapps.pico.background.BackgroundActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
</activity>
```

Orientation is given using querying to Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and getting the Media_ORIENTATION field

Comment: Where and how is `orientation` set?  What value does it have when you call `postRotate()`?

Comment: just use scaleType="matrix" for you ImageView

Comment: i get it from the systen Image table. this and the path is from the table... but the problem is that no matter what i set as orientation it doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

First get the **Degree** of **Orientation**

```
public static int getExifOrientation(String filepath) {
                int degree = 0;
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (exif != null) {
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
                        if (orientation != -1) {
                                // We only recognise a subset of orientation tag values.
                                switch (orientation) {
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                        degree = 90;
                                        break;
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                        degree = 180;
                                        break;
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                        degree = 270;
                                        break;
                                }

                        }
                }

                return degree;
        }
```

***Then use this Degree in your code to change the Rotation***

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();               
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);// get from getExifOrientation()
    //create new rotated bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: dont create a new Bitmap, use scaleType = "matrix" for the ImageView

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear the orientation value is given.. i'm querying Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to get Media.ORIENTATION and it has a value... no matter what value i insert - it doesn't work